# What is this manga that has a lot of superhero references?

Tags: story-identification, manga

I have read it quite some time back and forgotten its title. It is too hard to find via DDG, Google and MangaDex advanced search (tags tried include various combinations of: action, alien, drama, girl's love, magical girls, monster, superhero, tragedy).

I believe the manga started off focusing on a boy who wants to be a superhero to protect the world, but couldn't due to a lack of superpowers.

He ended up joining an agency that supports superheroes behind the frontlines, that initially consists of two sisters. The younger sister used to be a magical girl, but retired after losing her powers. She was very clingy to her older sister.

Later in the manga,

> the younger sister was still able to tap into her magical girl powers to stop the final villain, at the cost of her ability to walk.

It referenced / parodied a lot of other superheroes or superhero tropes, such as ultraman, superman, a hornet? dude (whose looks may be based off of spiderman) and a speedster.

At one point,

> the speedster reenacted the MCU quicksilver scene by dying to protect the hornet guy.

> There was also a spark guy who tried to became more powerful, and ended up being manipulated by the final villain in a monster-like form. He ended up being killed by the daughter of the superman as his condition was irreversible, leaving behind a wife and young daughter.

The ending of the manga involved

> an ex-disciple of the superman killing him, revealing himself to be the final villain. He has powers related to biological cells, and has been using it to manipulate various people / monsters. The remaining superheroes teamed up to defeat him.

> The manga finally ends with kamen rider going to the agency for advice, complaining that there is nothing for him to do as the world is at peace.

**Edit**

I posted this question on Lemmy originally: https://lemmy.world/post/11524756

The suggestions so far are:

- [Hero Union BBS](https://mangadex.org/title/c6a51a13-74fd-46bd-989e-5cdaa26542f6/hero-union-bbs)
- [Hero Company](https://mangadex.org/title/7a4ff526-0aea-432b-872c-863493525ddf/hero-company)
- [Ratman](https://mangadex.org/title/fca9850f-f20b-4fa4-ae43-e383c5af3aa2/ratman)
- [Concrete Revolutio](https://mangadex.org/title/5f36c5fa-f218-450a-96cd-edc5e3a436aa/concrete-revolutio-choujin-gensou)

However, none of these mangas are what I am looking for.

Comment: Hi. Was this full colour or mostly black & white? And roughly how many chapters did it have?

Comment: Hi there. I believe it is mostly black and white. Regarding number of chapters, I think it is a mid-length manga: not too short (~10 to 20 chapters), but not too long (~100 to 200+ chapters) either.

Comment: In roughly which year did you read this?

Comment: I think I read it 4 to 8 years ago, so 2016 to 2020.

Comment: Thanks @LogicDictates. Your prompts led me to think of AniList advanced search. Looks like the tags are rather incomplete on MangaDex.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's [*Gamma*](https://anilist.co/manga/86096/-Ganma) (AKA *γ:Ganma*, AKA γ-ガンマ-).

> It's an age where aliens, monsters and other dangers threaten the
> Earth, and various heroes have risen to protect it. Supporting these
> heroes are the human defense forces, of which the Kitajishi sisters
> Miyuki and Yuri are a part. Specifically, their office is for hero
> consultation, and they help heroes solve their problems, but they also
> help evacuation procedures during emergencies. Yuri was formerly an
> immensely powerful and popular magic girl, but now she helps protect
> people in a more human way. In their first case, they consult with a
> hero who has lost his powers, and is trying to find a way to live as
> an ordinary human.
>
> [image]

I found it by using AniList advanced search with the following tags:

- genres: superhero, yuri
- format: manga
- publishing status: finished
- country of origin: japan
- minimum date percentage: 18%
- year range: 2005 to 2022

Comment: You will be able to self-accept by clicking on the check mark by the voting buttons, although you won't be able to complete that process until 48 hours after you ask the question. You can improve your answer by explaining why this manga matches, as well as providing a plot summary.

Comment: @Endmaker - Well done. I found it as well, but I evidently spent too long working on my answer.